# Echoing a <div> and obtaining the id of it

Tags: php, html

Currently, when displaying all posts made by users I do the following:

```
while($info=mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
echo "<div id = 'posts'>";
   echo $info['subject'];
   echo $info['post-item'];
echo "</div>";

}
```

But, however, I now need to treat each element fetched as an actual post rather than just an outputted `div` for obtaining the post_id of each post to be able to actually enable a user to interact with different posts e.g. to 'like' a post.

I had tried hyperlinking the like  `href` to `?id=$thispost` which worked for liking however had problems such as a user altering the url, or even if I would like to also add the commenting functionality, I would need a different method!

Comment: mysql_fetch_array is deprecated. Use pdo or mysqli instead

Comment: does any of the returned data in `$info` contain a unique ID, which you in turn can use for reference?

Comment: @JoshuaBurns `$info['post_id'];`can return the post_id which is the unique id for a post. However, I am not sure how to obtain this if a user clicks a hyperlink below each separate post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for different tasks, you would pass different querystrings:

```
<a href="page.php?do=like&id=2">like this</a>
<a href="page.php?do=comment&id=2">comment</a>
<a href="page.php?do=share&id=2">share this</a>
```

In `page.php`, you would then...

```
if (isset($_GET['do'] && isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $do = $_GET['do'];
    $id = $_GET['id'];
} else exit("blabla");

switch ($do) {

    case 'like':
        // do sth
        break;

    case 'comment':
        // do sth
        break;

    // etc.

} // switch
```

Of course, passing the values by URL open the gate to manipulation.
So either store `$do` and `$id` in `$_SESSION` or in `$_POST`.

Example for `$_POST`:

```
$h = "";
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {

    $h .=  '<div id = "posts">';
    $h .= '<form method="post" action="page.php">';
    $h .= "{$info['subject']}<br />{$info['post-item']}";
    $h .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\” value=\”{$info['id']}\” />';
    $h .= '<input type="submit" name="do" value="like" />';
    $h .= '</form></div>';

}
echo $h;
```

Comments:
1. don't use `mysql_*`, but `mysqli_*` or `PDO` -> makes your code future-proof and more secure
2. this code creates a form around every post, with a hidden field containing the id (from db) of that post...
3. and a button that will send the id invisible for the user to `page.php`.
4. in `page.php`, you read `$_POST`, as in my above exaple with `$_GET`:

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $do = $_POST['do'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
} else exit("blabla"); 

// etc.
```

Comment: ah! that's what I have been trying to think of, instead I have been trying something like `id=2` whereas I could have simply changed it and added the relevant word for each! Such as like, comment etc. Thank you! So in terms of if someone would come and simply change the url number. Is there any way of avoiding this?

Comment: @user1888378: see my additions!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help you did solve my problem. However, using this method seems to be causing me problems. I am trying to use javascript when a user clicks the comment hyperlink and this should show a hidden div on the same page. However, because of the parameters, the javascript does not work as it has to change it's page according to the `?do=comment&id=2`